# Passing PHP session id to FLEX app

Tags: php, apache-flex, session

I'm developing a FLEX application which has a Java Server as back-end.

What I need:
-The FLEX app can only be used if the user it's logged;
-The FLEX app also needs to know which user it's logged, because it will shows especific content about him;
-I need to perform authentication on every webservice call;

However, the webpages are being developed using **PHP**, as well the login system.

After some digging, I've discovered that I can use the PHP session ID for authenticate every webservice calls, by using the php-java-bridge so both PHP and Java can share the same session.

My problem it's that I don't know how the FLEX app can get the current PHP session ID. I know that it's possible to pass it by flashvars, but I think it's not secure.

If someone has other solution, even not using the PHP session id, I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I see no benefit for Flex to access the PHP Session ID directly; are you sure that's what you need?

The SWF files that Flex creates are intended as client side software.  Whereas PHP and Java are usually used as server side software.  Try not to treat your Flex app as if it were a server side program.

The way most web applications handle sessions is that the server sets some cookie on the client.  The browser automatically passes that cookie with every request; and the server uses that cookie value to sync the request up with a server side session.I know ColdFusion and Java work like this and I assume PHP uses a similar mechanism.

Every time that your SWF (AKA Flex App) makes a request to the remote server, the request will include all cookies set by the server, just like it is a normal browser request.  The server should automatically sync the Flex request to a server side session.

Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

you can have a php page that will be called by flex using httpService, return the $_SESSION['userName'] or your session variable. if returned empty. stop the loading of the program. hope it make sense. coz i did the same thing..

Comment: Thanks! Actually, it makes sense. So, if I use SSL, there's no security issues by using this solution, am I right?

Comment: I was wondering, it is possible to tamper the data sent by the server, isn't it? How can I avoid this to make my application safe?